# SQL: status flips between 1 and 2; select all statuses, which are 2 since the last time it was 1

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have write only DB log of changes I keep track of (or statuses) and values fluctuate between 1 and 2. In the below table; ID is identity column, STATUS is either 1 or 2 and USER is a user id.

[image]

If the latest status (i.e. max ID) for a given user is 1 then my query should return nothing (1 = good). So running the query against the data above would be just that.

Here comes my question: I want to query for all statuses of 2 since the last time it was 1. Here is sample data:

[image]

In this case my query should return 2 and 3 (ID) because these have statuses of 2 since the last time it was 1.

This next query should return nothing because the latest status for this user was switched to 1:

[image]

And finally this next one should return 5 (because the latest status is 2 since the last time it was 1):

[image]

There is no date field in this table, you can only work with MAX(ID) ... GROUP BY ID, USER

How can I do this? I'm using MS SQL 2016.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use windowed aggregates to do this

```
WITH T
     AS (SELECT ID,
                STATUS,
                [USER],
                MAX(CASE WHEN Status = 1 THEN ID END) OVER ( PARTITION BY [USER]) AS MaxS1
         FROM   YourTable)
SELECT *
FROM   T
WHERE  Status = 2
       AND (ID > MaxS1  OR MaxS1 IS NULL)
```

Remove the `OR MaxS1 IS NULL` if you don't want the rows returned for users that have `2` and have never had `1` as a status

Answer (score 1):

You can filter with `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where 
    t.status = 2
    and not exists (
        select 1 from mtyable t1 where t1.user = t.user and t1.id > t.id and t1.status = 1
    )
```

This phrases as: all records with status `2` that have no following record (ie  a record with the same `user` and a greatest `id`) with `status = 1`. If there are no records with `status = 1` for a given user, all its records will be returned.

This can also be expressed with a `left join` antipattern:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
left join mytable t1 on t1.user = t.user and t1.id > t.id and t1.status = 1
where t1.id is null and t.status = 2
```